# No module named 'sklearn.metrics.regression',can run on macos not the cloud server GPU

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

These are my code:

```
import pickle
model_params = pickle.load(open('./cp/logP/model_parameters.pkl', 'rb'))
```

This is error prompt:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_750/2728954011.py in <module>
----> 1 model_params = pickle.load(open('./cp/logP/model_parameters.pkl', 'rb'))

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.regression'
```

model_parameters.pkl,Its file path:cp/logP/model_parameters.pkl.

The file that encountered the error is also located under the 'cp' directory.

I can run this code in my own macos which has no GPU.When I upload it on to a GPU platform to run this code,it occurs the error above.

the gpu config:

```
PyTorch  1.6.0
Python  3.8(ubuntu18.04)
Cuda  10.1
RTX 2080 Ti(11GB) * 1
12 vCPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8255C CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

My own computer:

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
2.9 GHz (two core)Intel Core i5
8 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
torch version ='1.13.1'
```

I check the similar question,but they seems related to the problems about "wrong way to import sklearn".

But I didn't use the scikit-learn,unless the pickle use it in its internal code.I don't know how to solve these,anyone can help?

1.additional info:

```
the model_parameters.pkl can be found in: https://github.com/isayev/ReLeaSE
```

[image]

2.additional info:
I said that the code can run on my macOS. The configurations include the following:
(1)Running on pycharm
(2)Library listed in requirements.txt:

```
absl-py==0.15.0
aiofiles==22.1.0
aiosqlite==0.18.0
anyio==3.6.2
appnope==0.1.3
argcomplete==2.1.2
argon2-cffi==21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
arrow==1.2.3
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==22.2.0
Babel==2.12.1
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.0
bleach==6.0.0
cached-property==1.5.2
cachetools==5.3.0
certifi @ file:///private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_477u68wvzm/croot/certifi_1671487773341/work/certifi
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
clang==5.0
colorlog==6.7.0
coverage==7.2.2
cycler==0.11.0
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
distlib==0.3.6
entrypoints==0.4
exceptiongroup==1.1.1
fastjsonschema==2.16.3
filelock==3.10.7
flatbuffers==1.12
fonttools==4.38.0
fqdn==1.5.1
gast==0.4.0
google-auth==2.17.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.53.0
h5py==3.1.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.2.0
importlib-resources==5.12.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
ipykernel==6.16.2
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isoduration==20.11.0
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
json5==0.9.11
jsonpointer==2.3
jsonschema==4.17.3
jupyter-events==0.6.3
jupyter-server==1.23.6
jupyter-ydoc==0.2.3
jupyter_client==7.4.9
jupyter_core==4.12.0
jupyter_server_fileid==0.8.0
jupyter_server_ydoc==0.8.0
jupyterlab==3.6.2
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab_server==2.21.0
keras==2.6.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.4
Markdown==3.4.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
matplotlib==3.5.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mistune==2.0.5
mordred==1.1.2
nbclassic==0.5.3
nbclient==0.7.2
nbconvert==7.2.10
nbformat==5.8.0
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
networkx==2.6.3
notebook==6.5.3
notebook_shim==0.2.2
nox==2022.11.21
numpy==1.19.5
oauthlib==3.2.2
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.3.5
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.3
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==9.4.0
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
platformdirs==3.2.0
pluggy==1.0.0
prometheus-client==0.16.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.38
protobuf==3.20.3
psutil==5.9.4
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.14.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyrsistent==0.19.3
pytest==7.2.2
pytest-cov==4.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-json-logger==2.0.7
pytz==2023.3
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq==25.0.2
rdkit==2022.9.5
requests==2.28.2
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rfc3339-validator==0.1.4
rfc3986-validator==0.1.1
rsa==4.9
scikit-learn==0.20.2
scipy==1.7.3
seaborn==0.9.0
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six==1.15.0
sniffio==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.4
tensorboard==2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.6.0rc1
tensorflow-estimator==2.6.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.17.1
tinycss2==1.2.1
tomli==2.0.1
torch==1.13.1
torchvision==0.14.1
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.26.0
traitlets==5.9.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
uri-template==1.2.0
urllib3==1.26.15
virtualenv==20.21.0
wcwidth==0.2.6
webcolors==1.13
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.5.1
Werkzeug==2.2.3
wrapt==1.12.1
xgboost==0.81
y-py==0.5.9
ypy-websocket==0.8.2
zipp==3.15.0
```

3.about the file:
I loaded the file in my own computer,The file's content are the following:

```
{'use_cuda': False, 'random_seed': 42, 'world_size': 1, 'task': 'regression', 'data_layer': <class 'openchem.data.smiles_data_layer.SmilesDataset'>, 'use_clip_grad': False, 'batch_size': 128, 'num_epochs': 26, 'logdir': './checkpoints/logP/fold_4', 'print_every': 1, 'save_every': 5, 'train_data_layer': <openchem.data.smiles_data_layer.SmilesDataset object at 0x7f944d550ed0>, 'val_data_layer': <openchem.data.smiles_data_layer.SmilesDataset object at 0x7f944d55a3d0>, 'eval_metrics': <function r2_score at 0x7f9449d5c3b0>, 'criterion': MSELoss(), 'optimizer': <class 'torch.optim.adam.Adam'>, 'optimizer_params': {'lr': 0.005}, 'lr_scheduler': <class 'torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR'>, 'lr_scheduler_params': {'gamma': 0.98}, 'embedding': <class 'openchem.modules.embeddings.basic_embedding.Embedding'>, 'embedding_params': {'num_embeddings': 46, 'embedding_dim': 128, 'padding_idx': 45}, 'encoder': <class 'openchem.modules.encoders.rnn_encoder.RNNEncoder'>, 'encoder_params': {'input_size': 128, 'layer': 'LSTM', 'encoder_dim': 128, 'n_layers': 2, 'dropout': 0.8, 'is_bidirectional': False}, 'mlp': <class 'openchem.modules.mlp.openchem_mlp.OpenChemMLP'>, 'mlp_params': {'input_size': 128, 'n_layers': 2, 'hidden_size': [128, 1], 'activation': [<function relu at 0x7f94466a94d0>, <function identity at 0x7f944d2aaf80>], 'dropout': 0.0}}
```

4.additional info:
the cloud server's library:

```
absl-py==0.14.1
anyio==3.3.2
argon2-cffi==21.1.0
attrs==21.2.0
Babel==2.9.1
backcall==0.2.0
bleach==4.1.0
brotlipy==0.7.0
cachetools==4.2.4
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cffi_1625807838443/work
chardet @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/chardet_1607706746162/work
conda==4.10.3
conda-package-handling @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-package-handling_1618262148928/work
cryptography @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cryptography_1616769286105/work
cycler==0.10.0
debugpy==1.4.3
decorator==5.1.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
entrypoints==0.3
future==0.18.2
google-auth==1.35.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
grpcio==1.41.0
idna @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/idna_1610986105248/work
ipykernel==6.4.1
ipython==7.28.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.6.5
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==3.0.1
joblib==1.2.0
json5==0.9.6
jsonschema==4.0.1
jupyter-client==7.0.5
jupyter-core==4.8.1
jupyter-server==1.11.0
jupyterlab==3.1.14
jupyterlab-language-pack-zh-CN==3.1.post1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
jupyterlab-server==2.8.2
jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
kiwisolver==1.3.2
Markdown==3.3.4
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
matplotlib==3.4.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
nbclassic==0.3.2
nbclient==0.5.4
nbconvert==6.2.0
nbformat==5.1.3
nest-asyncio==1.5.1
notebook==6.4.4
numpy==1.21.2
oauthlib==3.1.1
packaging==21.0
pandas==2.0.0
pandocfilters==1.5.0
parso==0.8.2
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.3.2
prometheus-client==0.11.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
protobuf==3.18.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
Pygments==2.10.0
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1608057966937/work
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.18.0
PySocks @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pysocks_1605305779399/work
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pyzmq==22.3.0
rdkit==2022.9.2
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1608241421344/work
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
rsa==4.7.2
ruamel-yaml-conda @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ruamel_yaml_1616016699510/work
scikit-learn==1.2.1
scipy==1.10.1
seaborn==0.11.2
Send2Trash==1.8.0
six @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/six_1623709665295/work
sniffio==1.2.0
supervisor==4.2.2
tensorboard==2.6.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
terminado==0.12.1
testpath==0.5.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
torch @ http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.5.1%2Bcu101-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
torchvision @ http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.6.1%2Bcu101-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
tornado==6.1
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1625563689033/work
traitlets==5.1.0
tzdata==2022.7
urllib3 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/urllib3_1625084269274/work
wcwidth==0.2.5
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.2.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
```

Comment: What kind of model or serialized object do you have in that file?
Which libraries are installed in each environment?
It seems that the problem is that the cloud environment needs sklearn to be installed, maybe it's used internally to represent the parameters of the model, it's impossible to say for sure without knowing all the info of your environments and what it's serialized.

Comment: @Jose I added related info.It seems that the file contains some paramters.It is used as initialization parameter for a model.

Comment: so at the end it was about the version, I am glad you solve it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problems.This is my solution:

1.I change the python from 3.8 to 3.7.

2.Install the scikit-learn==0.20.0

I am not sure if the PyTorch version is a crucial factor:
pytroch from 1.5.1 to 1.1.0.